# why In this case I'm not setting the property of the base class

Tags: c#, oop

I finally have time to teach one child to  understand and play with access modifiers and oop base and this keyword.

and I made one simple I think the simplest class in the world

```
public class Creature
{
    protected string Name {get; private set; }
    protected int Numberlegs { get; set; }

    public Creature(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }



    protected void Walk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Walking, walking, walking ....In Creature Method");
    }
}
```

So here is the derived class Mammal

```
public class Mammal : Creature
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Mammal(string namen, int age)
        : base(namen)
    {
        this.Age = age;
        base.Numberlegs = 4;
    }

    public void Sleep()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Shhh! {0} is sleeping!", this.Name);
    }

    public void Walk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Name+ " has started walking with "+this.Numberlegs + " legs");
        base.Walk();
    }
```

Tha case is so simple -You see I got a protected property `Numberlegs` in `Creature` Class;

In `Mammal` class in the constructor  I've got

```
    base.Numberlegs = 4;
```

SO I know that this row should set the `Numberlegs` property but not in `Mamal` class, but in its base class -> `Creature`.
And I thought that when I call in Walk() method OF `MAMAL`  class this.Numberlegs will be 0 -> but it's  4;

Comment: In your code there is no overriding of the property Numberlegs in the Mammal class, so the property is just the one that it had inherited from the base class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumberOfLegs is defined in baseclass. Mamal doesn't re-implement the property with new.

Hence there is no distinction between base.NumberOfLegs and this.NumberOfLegs

Answer (score 2):

SO I know that this row should set the Numberlegs property but not in Mamal class, but in its base class -> Creature

That's the whole point of inheriting from the Creature class, you don't need to re-declare NumberOfLegs - all children of Creature will automatically get that property.  You aren't explicitly declaring a new NumberOfLegs, so the base's will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Using `base` and `this` is completely superfluous in your case. These keywords are useful when you need to solve naming conflicts.

In your case `base.Numberlegs` and `this.Numberlegs` denotes the exact same property — `Creature.Numberlegs`. Why? Because there's no *other* `Numberlegs` declared in `Mammal`. Instead, `Mammal` *ihnerits* everything from `Creature`, which is the very nature of inheritance.

Only in the following cases would `base.Numberlegs` and `this.Numberlegs` denote different properties:

Two properties named the same:

```
class Creature 
{
    protected int Numberlegs { get; set; }
}

class Mammal : Creature
{
    // new declaration of a property Numberlegs, coincidentally named 
    // the same as Numberlegs in the base class
    protected new int Numberlegs { get; set; } // notice the 'new' keyword

    void Method()
    {
        base.Numberlegs; // denotes Creature.Numberlegs
        this.Numberlegs; // denotes Mammal.Numberlegs
    }
}
```

Virtual property, overriden in the descendant:

```
class Creature 
{
    protected virtual int Numberlegs { get; set; }
}

class Mammal : Creature
{
    protected override int Numberlegs { get; set; }

    void Method()
    {
        base.Numberlegs; // denotes Creature.Numberlegs
        this.Numberlegs; // denotes Mammal.Numberlegs
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG I think I haven't used inheritance for ages and I'm so asleep that I asked this silly question. Thank you for refreshing my knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
public class Creature
    {
        protected string Name { get; private set; }
        protected int Numberlegs { get; set; }

        public Creature(string name, int numLegs)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Numberlegs = numLegs;
        }



        protected void Walk()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Walking, walking, walking ....In Creature Method");
        }
    }
```

and Mammal:

public class Mammal : Creature
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }

```
    public Mammal(string namen, int age)
        : base(namen, 4)
    {
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public void Sleep()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Shhh! {0} is sleeping!", this.Name);
    }

    public void Walk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Name + " has started walking with " + this.Numberlegs + " legs");
        base.Walk();
    }
}
```

Then in your program:

Mammal m = new Mammal("hello", 20);
            m.Walk();

You will see 4 legs ;)